# How to set text in textview from array

Tags: java, android, arrays, textview, flipview

I am trying to get the values I have in an array to a text view, I am using a [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) and I would like to change the textview at the same time the image changes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < imagens.length && i < categories.length; i++) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
    simpleViewFlipper.addView(imageView);

    info_text3.setText(Arrays.toString(categories));
}

Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
simpleViewFlipper.setInAnimation(in);
simpleViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(out);
simpleViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
simpleViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
```

The image part is working and setting the text to the textview is also working, the problem is that the textview is static and that the text in the text view is the entire array and I just want one value, I was thinking linking the array with the 'i' from the for sentence, how can I do this?

Comment: What is the format of categories? Data type?

Comment: Why would you need to convert array into string? just pass the array index of which you want to set in textView

Comment: Is categories a array list of simple array?

Comment: It's a array of strings

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

```
  info_text3.setText(categories[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access arrays values at any index

```
info_text3.setText(categories[i]);
```

**1.** Create a layout with an image and a text view as mentioned below:

**custom_view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/element_spacing"
        android:text="Text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/yourimage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**2.** Inflate that layout

```
View customView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
```

**3.** Add custom view to viewflipper.

```
simpleViewFlipper.addView(customView);
```

**FINAL CODE**

```
for (int i = 0; i < imagens.length && i < categories.length; i++) {
    View customView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
    TextView info_text3 = customView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ImageView imageView = customView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
    simpleViewFlipper.addView(customView);

    info_text3.setText(categories[i]);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before, but it wasn't working or at least I though so, it does work but the last value stays there and I don't even get to see the others, how can I make it change at the same time as the image?

Comment: Are you using this in adapter? Please share the full code to identify last value issue

Comment: yes, I'm doing that right now (see anddevmanu answer) but the textview isn't showing up only the image, I didn't noticed you'de edited your code

Comment: Please see the updated code (step by step). You can directly run the FINAL CODE in the answer

Comment: It doesn't let inflate the layout, it says 'Cannot resolve method getLayoutInflater()'

Comment: In which class you have written this code? Are you writing this code in your activity? Share your code please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143389/discussion-between-alb-and-user12345).